# Ubuntu installation, bios is broken

Tags: boot

I´m trying to install Ubuntu in a partition in my computer and the problem comes when i start from my flash drive to start the installation, a message says broken bios is suspectect and then, the purple screen with the ubuntu logo starts to load but it freeze, i´ve seen people whith the same problem in msi computers (mine is msi P60 6QE) but apparently the solution is to use the option nomodeset in the installation menu but for me it freezes before that step so i don´t know how can i do.

Comment: If you press Esc while in the purple screen, do you get to the text output of the boot process?

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked and i installed ubuntu, but now the problem is that after restart, the typical black screen says something like core#2 stuck after 22 seconds a it repeats non stop , any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Typical steps would be making sure your bios is the latest version available - update if not.

Comment: Sorry, how can i do that?

Comment: Enter your bios, find its version number, google the current bios version for your hardware - you might find a type idientifier on the same screen as your bios version if you are lucky - then read and follow the instructions for a bios upgrade by your manufacturer if your version is older than the one available.